# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping null

Tags: c#, mapper

I have a form HTML in asp.net mvc that I want to save data as new row in db and I used Mapper.Map for the viewmodel and domain itself.
this is the exact error:

"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nCollateralViewModel -> Collateral\r\nViewModels.CollateralViewModel -> Domain.Entities.Collateral\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nCollateral\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nViewModels.CollateralViewModel"}

inner exception: null.

My config is this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Collateral, CollateralViewModel>();
```

Save calls then the Create from the controller.

```
 public CollateralViewModel Save(CollateralViewModel model, string username)
            {
                CollateralViewModel collateral = null;
                if (model.Id == 0)
                    collateral = CreateCollateral(model, username);
                else collateral = UpdateCollateral(model, username);

               return collateral;
            }

     private CollateralViewModel CreateCollateral(CollateralViewModel model, string username)
            {
                var newCollateral = ModelToDomain(model);

            }

    //this line throws an error 
     //Mapper.Map<CollateralViewModel, Collateral>(model);
    public Collateral ModelToDomain(CollateralViewModel model)
            {
                Collateral collateral = Mapper.Map<CollateralViewModel, Collateral>(model);
                return collateral;
            }
```

**but it works on UPDATE that calls this:**

```
    public CollateralViewModel DomainToModel(Collateral collateral)
            {
                CollateralViewModel model = Mapper.Map<Collateral, CollateralViewModel>(collateral);

                return model;
            }
```

I also tried instantiating first like this but same error:

```
public Collateral ModelToDomain(CollateralViewModel model)
        {
            Collateral collateral = new Collateral(); 
collateral  = Mapper.Map<CollateralViewModel, Collateral>(model);
            return collateral;
        }
```

I also tried doing this, for the properties not in the Domain:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Collateral, CollateralViewModel>()
                .ForMember(x => x.AssetGroupTypes, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.Client, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.CollateralInstrumentTypes, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.CollateralId, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.Currencies, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.RoundingMethods, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

is there anything I missed? I pretty new at using this. any help? thanks

Comment: You didn't map CollateralViewModel to Collateral. So, you need to create another map which converts CollateralViewModel to Collateral or you can call ReverseMap() in Mapper.CreateMap<Collateral, CollateralViewModel>() .

Comment: that fixed it! thanks.